# Excel define wildcard or variable as a letter of the alphabet

Tags: excel, vba, variables, wildcard

I have an excel sheet containing info as follows. All the text is contained in one cell. I would like to return the starting point of the first occurence of `") [letter of the alphabet]"`. In this example, `") r"`. I need the position where `"r"` is to stand as a wildcard for any letter of the alphabet. I have tried playing around with the FIND and SEARCH functions. But I am unable to incorporate a wildcard or a variable denoting a letter of the alphabet `(`as opposed to a character like `/`, `[` or `(`.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

`右手 [みぎて] /(n) right hand/(P)/EntL1171120X/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an array formula:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(") "&CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("97:122"))),$A$1),0))
```

Enter array formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

**How it works**

Characters 97 through 122 are the letters "a" through "z".  `SEARCH` does a case-insensitive search, so this would also catch the letters "A" through "Z".  If you prefer a case-sensitive search, replace `SEARCH` with `FIND`.

I used `INDIRECT`, so the formula wouldn't be changed if you moved or copied it to another row.

For each letter of the alphabet that's not found, `SEARCH` returns a #VALUE! error.  The `IFERROR` function changes those errors to 0.

In this example, the array `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` is fed to the `MAX` function.  Note the number 13 in the 18th spot.  That's because the letter "r" is the 18th letter of the alphabet.

The code above would return the *last* occurrence of the pattern, or 0 if not found.  To return the *first* occurrence, you could replace `MAX` with `MIN`, and change `IFERROR` to return a large number if not found, such as 999:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(") "&CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("97:122"))),A1),999))
```

(Remember to enter as an array formula.)

However, this will return 999 if not found.  To return 0 instead, simply substitute 0 for 999:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(") "&CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("97:122"))),A1),999)),999,0)
```

Comment: Brilliant. It works as desired for the vast majority of the cells. There are some with more than one occurrence of ") [letter of the alphabet]". Is there a way to return the position of the first occurrence? In the below example, I would be looking for ") together.."  <br/>一緒(P);一しょ(io) [いっしょ] /(n-adv,n,adj-no) (1) (See 御一緒) together/(2) at the same time/(3) same/identical/(P)/EntL1163400X/

Comment: Absoutely brilliant. The day I become fluent in Japanese, I will remember you. どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards aren't flexible enough to do what you want. You can use Regex in VBA.

To do so first you have to 'activate' Regex. In VBA environment select menu Tools->References and check 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions'. After that you can use a piece of code like that (assuming your cell of interest is 'A1' in 'Sheet1'):

```
Sub FindSomething()
    Dim r As RegExp
    Dim m As MatchCollection
    Set r = New RegExp
    r.Pattern = "\) [A-Za-z]"
    Set m = r.Execute(Sheet1.Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

m is a MatchCollection with all occurences of what you look for. If `m.Count` is bigger than 0 there is at least one hit. `FirstIndex` of the single MatchCollection Items indicate the positions in the original text.